# Does HttpClient singleton resolved from IHttpClientFactory respect dns changes?

Tags: c#, httpclient

There is problem with using singleton HttpClient instances that it does not respect dns changes. IHttpRequestFactory solves it, but it is intended to resolve new instance per request. How does it behave if HttpClient is resolved once(from IHttpRequestFactory) and used for many requests? Does it respect dns changes?

If yes how should I deal with it - get new HttpClient for each request?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: You should probably be using IHttpClientFactory instead

Comment: If you uses `HttpClientFactory`, it doesn't matter how use the client, its all done for you internally, you can dispose it, hold on to it, wrap it up and give it to your dog etc. However, you should research this for your self, there are some great features that have been introduced and its worth your learning

Comment: @Llama these docs do not mention usage of http client as singleton, just single flow with per request scope is described.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. The original advice was always to use HttpClient as a singleton / static instance, which is what I thought you were referring to. I didn't realise you meant that you were using it in a singleton in conjunction with IHttpClientFactory.

Comment: @Llama the problem with singleon HttpClient is that it does not respect dns changes. So if you do blue-green deplyoments and change load balancer to point to other env it will fail.
I do not have blue-green deployments yet, but I want to know how to use HttpClient to avoid problems in future.

Comment: Again: I misunderstood. I thought you were referring to the original advice from Microsoft re using a static/singleton instance of `HttpClient`. That is how I interpreted your question. I did not interpret your question as "I am using HttpClient in a service registered as a singleton" as that is not what you said. I understand what the issues are, but your setup wasn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using clients created by an implementation of IHttpClientFactory solves the stale DNS information problem.

The factory pools HttpMessageHandler instances, and, if its lifetime hasn't expired, a handler can be reused from the pool when the factory creates a new HttpClient instance.

The default expiration time is 2 minutes. After 2 minutes, connections inside the pool are dropped. If you later send a request to the same server, a new connection must be recreated and DNS will be queried again. The expiration time is configurable.

More more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests